# Angular render FormArray with 10k+ rows (15 columns per row) data in one page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, large-data, formarray

I have a requirement to render a form which include a FormArray with 10k+ rows data (15+ FormControls per row) in one page in my Angular 8 web application. Because of these large amount of data, there have a big render problem, can anyone help me to improve the render performance? Thank you

I have tried to use virtualScroll with `@angular/cdk`, but still works bad

```html
<table [formGroup]="validateForm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column.name}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <ng-container formArrayName="rows"
                  *ngIf="inputDataValid(rowDatas, columns)">
      <tbody *cdkVirtualFor="let row of rowDatas; let rowIndex = index; "
             [formGroupName]="rowIndex"
             class="example-item"
             >
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor="let column of columns;">
            <input type="text"
                   [formControlName]="column.prop"
                   *ngIf="column.controlType === controlTypes.TEXT">
            <select name=""
                    id=""
                    [formControlName]="column.prop"
                    *ngIf="column.controlType === controlTypes.SELECT">
<!-- options -->
</select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you paginate it? using infinityscroll or just a load more button.

Comment: Surely, all 10k rows at the same time is not a requirement? Is it a school project? If it's real world, paging would be the answer.

Comment: I would go for pagination with virtual Scroll

Comment: Unfortunately，the pagination is not allowed ， that's user's specific requirements to show and modify these data in one page

Answer (score 0):

In the **ng-container**, you have an **ngIf** that is calling a function to validate the data. As you may know, the ngIf is reevaluated every time there is a change (or event) detected by Angular. That validation over 10K+ rows for every time a UI event is detected will hit your performance badly. I Think you should run that validation when you receive the data and display some message (i.e. "Processing...")  indicating that you are waiting for a something to finish, then (after the validation is finished) display your data.

You can accomplish this by setting a boolean property that you set to **true** after the validation is done.

It may look like this:

```
<table [formGroup]="validateForm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column.name}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="!canDisplay">
       <tr><td>Processing...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <ng-container formArrayName="rows"
                  *ngIf="canDisplay">
      <tbody *cdkVirtualFor="let row of rowDatas; let rowIndex = index; "
             [formGroupName]="rowIndex"
             class="example-item"
             >
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor="let column of columns;">
            <input type="text"
                   [formControlName]="column.prop"
                   *ngIf="column.controlType === controlTypes.TEXT">
            <select name=""
                    id=""
                    [formControlName]="column.prop"
                    *ngIf="column.controlType === controlTypes.SELECT">
                <!-- options -->
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </ng-container>
</table>
```

Here **canDisplay** is a boolean property that (i.e. after validation is finished) is set to true when the data is ready to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I give up to use **FormArray** to modify the data, instead, use the  [TreeTable with TreeTableCellEditor in the library of Primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable), of course, with virtual scroll

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve a similar problem.  Using Chrome profiler, I found much time is spent on running validations repetitively.  Creating the form without validation helps, but still a bit too slow.

Disable the form array:

`validateForms.rows.disable({emitEvent: false});`

When creating each FormGroup row, disable each control:

```
FormBuilder.group({
    col1: [{value: 'value1', disabled: true }, validators... ],
    col2: [{value: 'value2', disabled: true }, validators... ],
});
```

Then after all groups are added to the array, enable the array:

`validateForm.rows.enable({onlySelf: false, emitEvent: false});`